# Linker script RAM intialization in ROM

Tags: c, gcc, ld, riscv

I am currently writing my own linker script to execute a baremetal RISC-V program.
I want to place in ROM (exactly at the address *_idata* if it is possible) initial values of global variables which are in RAM (at boot time, a program will be responsible to copy the different values from the ROM to the RAM).
To do this, I use the VMA/LMA mechanism.

Here is my linker script:

```
MEMORY
{
  ROM      (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00004000, LENGTH = 0x00004000
  RAM      (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x00008000, LENGTH = 0x00004000
}

STACK_SIZE  = 0x3000;
BOOT_PC     = 0x1000;

/* Section Definitions */
SECTIONS
{  

  /* Code and constants */
  .text :
  {
    _stext = . ;
    *(.rodata*);
    *(.srodata*);
    *(.text*);
    _etext = . ;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    /* Initial data of RAM */
    _idata = . ;
  } > ROM

  /* Initialized data */
  /* Relocate in ROM */
  .data : AT (_idata)
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _sdata = . ;
    *(.sdata .sdata.* .sdata2.*)
    *(.data .data.*)
    _edata = . ;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > RAM 

  /* Unitialized data */
  .bss (NOLOAD) :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _sbss = . ;
    *(.bss*);
    *(.sbss*);
    *(COMMON);
    _ebss = . ;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > RAM

  /* Stack */
  .stack (NOLOAD):
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    . = . + STACK_SIZE;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _stack = . ;
  } > RAM
}
```

And here is my basic C program test:

```
int d1 = 0x42;
const int d2 = 0x40;
int d3 = 0x35;


int main () {
  return 0;
}
```

However, surprisingly for me, the initial values are still placed in the RAM (except the *d2* constant):

```
00004000 <d2>:
    4000:   0040                    .2byte  0x40
    ...

00004004 <main>:
    4004:   00000513            li  x10,0
    4008:   00008067            ret

0000400c <_etext>:
    400c:   0000                    .2byte  0x0
    ...

Disassembly of section .data:

00008000 <d3>:
    8000:   0035                    .2byte  0x35
    ...

00008004 <d1>:
    8004:   0042                    .2byte  0x42
    ...
```

Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?
I read the [following information](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-LMA.html), I have also tested the syntax **> RAM AT > ROM** but still without success ...

Comment: Just a hunch, but if `d1` and `d3` are not `const`, so they can't end up in a read-only section? In contrast, `d2` is `const`, so it can be in read-only memory.

Comment: Yes, but here I just want the initial values of *d1* and *d3* in ROM. I want to be able to initialize them in RAM at boot time. Constant *d2* is here just to illustrate that my ROM exists.

Comment: So, declare `d1` and `d3` as `const` and copy them on startup to RAM as the answer by 0______ shows?

Comment: @Ludo Such linker scripts are supposed to do automatically what escou64 wants: Put the initial data in ROM, but allocate the variables in RAM. The copying is part of the startup code. The issue is the linker script, which seems to be erroneous.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy it as startup.

```
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

/* ... */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> ROM
```

The best is to have a separate startup C code, but as a workaround you can use gcc `constructor`

```
extern uint8_t _sdata[];
extern uint8_t _edata[];
extern uint8_t _sidata[];

static void __attribute__((constructor)) copyRAMfunctions(void)
{
    memcpy(_sdata, _sidata, _edata - sdata);
}
```

Comment: I already have this C function to initialize my values in RAM. My issue here is that initial values are not put in ROM by the linker but still in RAM. Then, I am not able to copy initial values from ROM to RAM ...

Comment: As @0___________ said, they ARE stored in ROM, at _sidata.

Comment: @escou64 read very carefully my linker script and yours and spot the differences. Those differences are very important. For example you do not have symbol having address at the load address